# Rails model inheritance

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

It will be simplest to explain with code example, in Python I can do so to achieve model inheritance:

```
"""Image model"""
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, String, Text
from miasto_3d.model.meta import Base

class Image(Base):
    __tablename__ = "image"
    image_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = Column(String(200))

    def get_mime(self):
        #function to get mime type from file
        pass



"""WorkImage model"""
class WorkImage(Image, Base):
    __tablename__ = "work_images"

    image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("image.image_id"), primary_key=True)
    work_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("work.id"))
    work = relation("Work", backref=backref('images',order_by='WorkImage.work_id'))

"""UserAvatar model"""
class UserAvatar(Image, Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_avatars"

    image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("image.image_id"), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    user = relation("User", backref=backref('images',order_by='UserAvatar.user_id'))
```

How I do similar things in Rails? Or maybe there is another, better way to do it?
I know paperclip, but I don't like it's conception to use shared table to store photo and model data.

Comment: You shouldn't need to inherit from `Image` *and* `Base` if `Image` already inherits from `Base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting either [a polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) or perhaps [single table inheritance](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815).

Comment: Can I define methods inside models just like in Pylons (`get_mime`)?

Comment: I have no experience with Pylons, but yes, you can define methods in polymorphic models and STI models.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't define database fields in the model, you cannot inherit database schema in this way - all your fields will need to be specified per table in a migration. You probably should use `paperclip`, if only because reinventing the wheel is a pain. It works really well, and abstracts away from the actual database structure for you.

In Rails, rather than model inheritance, shared functionality tends to be implemented in modules, like so:
http://handyrailstips.com/tips/14-drying-up-your-ruby-code-with-modules

Comment: But it is related not only to images, it can be e.g. addresses.

Comment: So you're saying you want to define some fields once and have many models use them? I think that limits your options to a) an object to hold your data and a polymorphic belongs to (a 'shared table' - i.e. People has_one: Address), b) define the same fields on multiple models.

Comment: Could you post some example of a)?